# Where I can find the filepath to a texture used in the Image Textue node?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, image, system

I'd like to edit the textures coming along with a packed blend file. I already did the 'unpacking' and set the paths to *absolute* using *External Data -> *Make all paths absolute*. However, I can not find the textures on my disk.

[image]

**Q:** Is there any way to see the *filepath* of a texture used for a certain *Image Texture* node to locate it on my hard drive?

Answer (score 5):

Click on the *Image Texture* node, hit <kbd>N</kbd> to open up the *Properties Panel* on the right side, go to *Item > Properties* and you'll get all image properties like the path, size, color space etc.:

[image]

See: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html

Comment: thanks very much :)